# Find mysql entries without match in other tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in mysql with the following structure:

```
Events: id
Events_artists: event_id, more columns
```

I would like to find the event_ids in the table events_artists that do not have a match with the id in events.

The only thing I have come up with so far is this:

```
SELECT * FROM events,events_artists WHERE events_artists.event_id!=events.id
```

However, that is crap and basically returns the whole table.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you!

Charles

SOLUTION FOUND, thanks to Andrzej Bobak

select * from events_artists where event_id not in (select id from events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
select * from events_artists where event_id is null or event_id not in (select id from events)
```

Comment: Glad to help you. In the future run proposed queries with "explain" or "explain analyze" (depends on database server). It will show you the query plan and allow you to optimize queries.

Comment: One more question, though: How come your solution returns a result with 0 rows, but stb's solutions returns more than 0? Is it really the same?

Comment: He checks null values. Forgot that in my query, now (after edit) it should be the same.

Comment: Thank you! But it still returns different values... Strange.

Comment: My query shows all the artists whose event ids either don't exist or don't match any id in events table. Paste some data and results of both queries. We'll see where's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from events_artists a
left join events b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```

your approach uses a cartesian product which joins every row with each other. So your `where` criteria just filters your result containing the rows that don't match, but that will be a lot because of the cartesian product

Comment: Thank you! It is a little slow somehow, tombom has already mentioned there might be something wrong with my database. I will have to check on that.

Comment: As tombom said, this should normally work fine. I'd have expected the 'not in' statement to be slower than ours.

Comment: As I commented tombom's solution. Run query analyzer and see whether your approach or mine is better for a given set of data.

Comment: @AndrzejBobak thanks! I've seen and checked it myself. Good point.